# FTP command submitted with Node.js Socket code is not processed

Tags: node.js, sockets, events, ftp

I have the following FTP session using telnet:

```
$ telnet ftp.fsn.hu 21
Trying 195.228.252.133...
Connected to ftp.fsn.hu.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 ftp.fsn.hu FTP server (Version 6.00LS) ready.
USER anonymous
331 Guest login ok, send your email address as password.
PASS joe@example.com
230 Guest login ok, access restrictions apply.
```

I tried to automatize this:

```
var net = require('net');

var sock = net.Socket();

var regex220 = /^220/;

var regex331 = /^331/;

var regex230 = /^230/;

sock.on('data', function (buffer)
  { console.log('data received:\n' + buffer);

    if (buffer.toString().match(regex220) !== null)
    {
      sock.write('USER anonymous');
      console.log("sent: 'USER anonymous'");
    } else if (buffer.toString().match(regex331) !== null)
    {
      sock.write('PASS joe@example.com');
      console.log("sent: 'PASS joe@example.com'");
    } else if (buffer.toString().match(regex230) !== null)
    {
      console.log('LOGGED IN');
    }
  });

sock.connect(21, 'ftp.fsn.hu');
```

Running this on Fedora 32 and Node.js 12.16.1 I get

```
$ node fsn.js
data received:
220 ftp.fsn.hu FTP server (Version 6.00LS) ready.

sent: 'USER anonymous'
```

and it hangs there.

Why this program does not go through the second and third round?

Comment: Oh well, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to terminate (submit) the command with CRLF:

```
sock.write('USER anonymous\r\n');
```